# equivalent inner-product vector for one

Tags: linear-algebra, estimation

I have a map that projects a $k$ dimensional vector $x$ to an $m$ dimensional vector $\phi(x)$.

The vector function (map) $\phi$ can be any linear or non-linear function of $x$, which is not necessarily invertible.

I define: $$<x,y>:=\phi(x)^T\phi(y)=\sum_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)$$

Now I'm looking for an estimated $\theta$, such that:

$$<x,\theta>:=\phi(x)^T\phi(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x)*1=\sum_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x)$$

My try: Clearly $$<x,\theta>:=\phi(x)^T\phi(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x)*1=\sum_{i=1}^m \phi_i(x)=\phi(x)^T\mathbf{1}$$, so we are looking for $\theta$'s that satisfy $\phi(\theta)=\mathbf{1}$, or equivalently: $\phi^{-1}(\mathbf{1})=\theta$.

I'm stuck here, because $\phi$ can be an arbitrary --highly nonlinear-- map, which is not necessarily invertible.

I think there should be a solution for efficiently approximating $\theta$.

My question: I don't need the set of $\theta$'s that exactly satisfy this constraint.
how can I estimate $\theta$ from sample projections?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) What is a "projected space"? Perhaps "projective space"? (2) How do you project a $\;k$- dimensional vector onto an $\;m$ - dimensional one?? Where does this all happen? What is the bigger space where these things live? (3) If you can have $\;\phi(x)=1\;$ , what is that $\;\phi\;$ ? A linear functional?

Comment: @Timbuc I don't think Alt means projective space; rather, I suspect they refer to the feature map used in the "kernel trick" commonly used in machine learning (where the $\phi$ is typically very much nonlinear)

Comment: @user7530, that's exactly my question. $\phi$ is in fact a feature map in the kernel trick.

Comment: Well, at least the highly misleading tags are removed now and the correct, apparently, tag is on. I've no idea what "machine learning" is and why it belongs to mathematics, but good luck.

Comment: @Timbuc, I edited the question to make it clear. And, btw, I believe that the linear algebra tag is relevant.

Comment: @Timbuc, so you believe this question is not a math question?

Comment: @Alt I can't say: I've no idea what machine-learning is and what a "feature map" is and what a "kernel trick" is and etc. Now, user7530 said the map $\;\phi\;$ is "typically very much non-linear", so I can't even understand how linear algebra kicks in here. But perhaps it does.

Comment: @Timbuc, Then, I think the machine-learning tag is not relevant, because I never used the "feature map", or "kernel trick" jargons in my question, those are just some applications. But do you think the word "map" needs to be defined :) ), I added a sentence to clarify that as well.

Comment: @Alt yes indeed: any question with maps in it should at least say what the domain is and, if possible, the function's definition. But perhaps that's not needed in machine-learning.

Comment: The issue is that the generic problem, "given an arbitrary nonlinear function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}^m$ find an element of the inverse image of $(1,\ldots,1)$" is a completely hopeless problem. So the more context you can give about what you're *really* trying to do, the more likely you are to get help here.